how to use multiple silders in Swiper 10, I tried Using Swiper elements with two <swiper-containers> and only on work in the project
I tried using swiper container and only work one slider at a time.
Slider 1
<swiper-container #swipercat  init="false">
<swiper-slide *ngFor="let displayResult of displayResults;" >
        <div class="doe-grid-card doe-grid-card--slideshow"   (click)="submitSearch(displayResult.name)" style="width: 95%;">
          <div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + displayResult.imageUrl + '),url('+'/assets/images/doe-image-missing.jpg'+')'}" class="doe-grid-card__img"></div>
          <div class="doe-grid-card__details" >
            <span class="doe-grid-card__title font-weight-bold base-font--x-large"  [ngClass]="{'w-100': displayResult.price == 0}" title="{{displayResult.name}}">{{displayResult.name}}</span>
            <div *ngIf="displayResult.price && displayResult.price>0" class="doe-grid-card__price">
              <label>{{displayResult.currency_display}}</label>
              <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ displayResult.price | number : '.2-2'}} {{ displayResult.currency}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </swiper-slide >
</swiper-container>

componenet file ngAfterInit()

const swiperEl = document.querySelector('swiper-container');

  // swiper parameters
  console.log("swiper parameters");
  const swiperParams = {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    grid: {
      rows: 2,
      fill:"row"
    },
    navigation: "true",
    breakpoints: {
        600: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
          slidesPerGroup: 2,
        },
        900: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
          slidesPerGroup: 3,
        },
        1400: {
          slidesPerView: 4,
          slidesPerGroup: 4,
        }
    },
    on: {
      init() {
        // ...
      },
    },
  };

  // now we need to assign all parameters to Swiper element
  Object.assign(swiperEl, swiperParams);

  // and now initialize it
  swiperEl.initialize();

Slider 2
  <swiper-container #swipercity  init="false"> 
        <swiper-slide *ngFor="let city of cities; let i = index;" 
        <div class="doe-grid-card doe-grid-card--top-content"
             (click)="submitSearch(city)" style="width: 95%;">
          <div class="doe-grid-card__img" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+city.imageUrl+'),url('+'/assets/images/header-banners/components/maldivista/image_missing.png'+')'}">
            <div class="doe-grid-card__top-title d-flex align-items-center">
              <i class="doe-icon doe-icon-australia" *ngIf='city.parentCode =="AU"'></i>
              <i class="doe-icon doe-icon-new-zealand" *ngIf='city.parentCode =="NZ"'></i>
              <i class="doe-icon doe-icon-fiji" *ngIf='city.parentCode =="FJ"'></i>
              <img src="../../assets/images/header-banners/components/maldivista/map-icon-maldives.png" alt="maldives Icon"  class="doe-icon maldivista-map-icon ml-2 align-middle"/>
              <span class="ml-2">{{city.parentName}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="doe-grid-card__details">
              <span class="doe-grid-card__title doe-grid-card__title--responsive w-100 line-h-x" title="{{city.name}}" *ngIf="city.name != null">
               {{city.name}}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </swiper-slide> 
    </swiper-container> 

componenet file ngAfterInit()

  // swiper element
    const swiperEl = document.querySelector('swiper-container');
  
    //swiper parameters
    console.log("swiper parameters");
    const swiperParams = {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      grid: {
        rows: 2,
        fill:"row"
      },
      navigation: "true",
      breakpoints: {
          500: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            slidesPerGroup: 2,
          },
          900: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            slidesPerGroup: 3,
          },
          1400: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            slidesPerGroup: 4,
          }
      },
      on: {
        init() {
          // ...
        },
      },
    };
  
    // now we need to assign all parameters to Swiper element
    Object.assign(swiperEl, swiperParams);
  
    // and now initialize it
    swiperEl.initialize();

I tried to add multiple sliders

Ensure each swiper has a unique template reference variable #swipercity1 for the first one and #swipercity2 for the second one the same name need to be set on the view child also!
The code document.querySelector('swiper-container') is selected the same swiper-container so only one gets rendered, instead use @ViewChild which is the angular way of implementing this!
ts
...

@ViewChild('swipercity1') swiper!: ElementRef<any>;
...

...
ngAfterInit()

  // swiper element
    const swiperEl: any = this.swiper.nativeElement;
  
    //swiper parameters
    console.log("swiper parameters");
    const swiperParams = {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      grid: {
        rows: 2,
        fill:"row"
      },
      navigation: "true",
      breakpoints: {
          500: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            slidesPerGroup: 2,
          },
          900: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            slidesPerGroup: 3,
          },
          1400: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            slidesPerGroup: 4,
          }
      },
      on: {
        init() {
          // ...
        },
      },
    };
  
    // now we need to assign all parameters to Swiper element
    Object.assign(swiperEl, swiperParams);
  
    // and now initialize it
    swiperEl.initialize();
}

...
html
<swiper-container #swipercity1  init="false">
    <swiper-slide *ngFor="let displayResult of displayResults;" >
        <div class="doe-grid-card doe-grid-card--slideshow"   (click)="submitSearch(displayResult.name)" style="width: 95%;">
          <div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + displayResult.imageUrl + '),url('+'/assets/images/doe-image-missing.jpg'+')'}" class="doe-grid-card__img"></div>
          <div class="doe-grid-card__details" >
            <span class="doe-grid-card__title font-weight-bold base-font--x-large"  [ngClass]="{'w-100': displayResult.price == 0}" title="{{displayResult.name}}">{{displayResult.name}}</span>
            <div *ngIf="displayResult.price && displayResult.price>0" class="doe-grid-card__price">
              <label>{{displayResult.currency_display}}</label>
              <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ displayResult.price | number : '.2-2'}} {{ displayResult.currency}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </swiper-slide >
</swiper-container>

